# How can I specify the snapshot (block number) in geth snap sync?

Tags: go-ethereum, snapshot

As shown in the picture here (https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/sync-modes), snap sync starts from a recent snapshot. I wonder if there is any way for me to specify an earlier snapshot for snap sync?

[image]